# Convert RGB to HEX programatically - Android

Tags: android, hex, rgb

So Im making an app that converts RGB Colors to Hexadecimal (ex. #FFFFFF). I have three edittext for Red, Green and Blu. When I input values for every edittext like (255,255,255) and I click the button the RGB values will be converted to Hexadecimal and will be shown in textview. Can someone help me with the computation here is my codes.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public String str = "";

    int i, num, numtemp;
    EditText showRed, showGreen, showBlue;
    String displayStr = "";
    Button zero, one, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine, clear, convert;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);

        showRed = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.red);
        showGreen = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.green);
        showBlue = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.blue);

        clear = (Button) findViewById(R.id.clear);
        convert = (Button) findViewById(R.id.convert);

        convert.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                //Convertion Computaion here HELP!!!!!!!!!
            }
        });

        clear.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                str = "";
                num = 0;
                numtemp = 0;

                showRed.setText("");
                showRed.requestFocus();
                showGreen.setText("");
                showBlue.setText("");
                displayStr = "";
            }
        });
    }

    public void btn1Clicked(View v) {
        insert(1);
    }

    public void btn2Clicked(View v) {
        insert(2);
    }

    public void btn3Clicked(View v) {
        insert(3);
    }

    public void btn4Clicked(View v) {
        insert(4);
    }

    public void btn5Clicked(View v) {
        insert(5);
    }

    public void btn6Clicked(View v) {
        insert(6);
    }

    public void btn7Clicked(View v) {
        insert(7);
    }

    public void btn8Clicked(View v) {
        insert(8);
    }

    public void btn9Clicked(View v) {
        insert(9);
    }

    public void btn0Clicked(View v) {
        insert(0);
    }

    private void insert(int j) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if (showRed.hasFocus()) {
            str = str + Integer.toString(j);
            num = Integer.valueOf(str).intValue();
            displayStr += Integer.toString(j);

            showRed.setText(displayStr);

            if ((showRed.length() == 3)) {
                displayStr = "";
                showGreen.requestFocus();
            }
        } else if (showGreen.hasFocus()) {

            str = str + Integer.toString(j);
            num = Integer.valueOf(str).intValue();
            displayStr += Integer.toString(j);

            showGreen.setText(displayStr);

            if ((showGreen.length() == 3)) {
                displayStr = "";
                showBlue.requestFocus();
            }
        } else if (showBlue.hasFocus()) {
            str = str + Integer.toString(j);
            num = Integer.valueOf(str).intValue();
            displayStr += Integer.toString(j);

            showBlue.setText(displayStr);

            if ((showBlue.length() == 3)) {
                displayStr = "";
                showBlue.clearFocus();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html

Comment: @pskink I need help with the computation of my codes :( please

Comment: i sent you a link to a class that has methods to convert red, green and blue to int color, did you read it?

Comment: I need to make my own algorithm for the conversion

Comment: what algorithm, are. Color methods wrong?

Answer (score 4):

Just pass an array of 3 colors red, green, blue to this function

```
  int[] color={200,170,100};
  btn.setBackgroundColor(getHexColor(color));


  public static int getHexColor(int[] color) {
    return android.graphics.Color.rgb(color[0], color[1], color[2]);
 }
```